# Trying to get to the bottom of a (likely) overheating issue---is my ps unit too close to the motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, cooling

What say you to this configuration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I love that case, that was back when they were really solid.. it opened so nicely. That was before they went like the antec ones, as horrible to open as any other case!  I don't think distance of power supply to CPU is ever the cause of an overheating issue - I haven't heard of it, and can't see how.  There are two types of power supply designs.. fans on the bottom sucking and a fan blowing out the back. And, the older, fan on the back of the PSU, and most like that also have no grill on the bottom of the psu. Either way, that/a 120mm fan on the back of the case will do a good job.

Comment: What model of case is that?  I bought one like it about 6 years ago, but years later I couldn't get hold of it.  I then got annoyed with it 'cos the lack of space between PSU and CPU meant I couldn't use a super fat CPU HSF. But other than that, I liked it a lot.

Comment: barlop, thanks for the reply. I appreciate your comments about the case. Especially since I was debating getting a larger one, like one with a grill on top and in front--my doesn't have one in front, just at the floor. For what it's worth, it's an "ibox orion". This is as close to a manufacturer's pic as I could find http://www.geoinf.pl/img/zdjecia/OBU/OBUIBOAXT0182.jpg. Again, thanks for the positive words--I think I'll stay with the case then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that big grill at the back of your case? You need a case fan there. That should resolve at least some of the heating issues you're having. Make sure it's an exhaust fan, though.

And no, the configuration of your 500W power supply is standard in relation to the motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I took the fan off for some dust cleaning when I took the pic.

Comment: Cool. Tog's advice about the cabling is valid, too. You want to have air flowing over top of the board and the cables are obstructing that.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how hard the PSU fan is working it's hard to tell. I would be inclined to move those cables away from the memory slots, though, as the memory cards are just as susceptible to heat as everything else.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but do cables generate heat to cause issues? Maybe that's my problem....

Comment: No, they don't generate heat, however they do obstruct airflow.